# RedirectMatch to clean badly formatted URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I received notification from the Google Search Console that it had detected a redirection error for this URL:

```
http://reiki.7gen.com/doreiki.htm' target=
```

I am suspecting that somewhere in the universe there is a link to that page that is mangled like so:

```
<a href="http://reiki.7gen.com/doreiki.htm' target="_blank">anchor</a>
```

Notice the single quote when it should have been double quotes.  This site has existed since 1995 hence back then it was common to use `.htm` as the extension.

The old domain for this site is `reiki.7gen.com` and there is a shadow of the old site where there is an `.htaccess` that takes care of redirecting to the new domain at `thereikipage.com`

I'm thinking, I don't know where the referrer is, so what if instead I fix this in the `.htaccess`.  That is, detect this mangled URL and rewrite it correctly.

This is what I've tried with no luck:

```
RedirectMatch permanent /doreiki.htm\'(.*) https://thereikipage.com/doreiki.html
```

Comment: Why do people always try to solve the last bit of the internet, even those bits they cannot see or investigate? Why should you be interested in a single invalid reference to your page and why should _you_ try to "fix" that?

Comment: I am interested in fixing it because the Google Search Console is reporting it as a problem, and I believe that any item reported in the Search Console will be a negative mark against the website overall and affect search rankings.

I believe in being a responsible website owner and fixing things up to improve user experience and not needlessly cause problems.

Comment: I personally would advise to enhance the content instead. That is a much better investment of your time.